# check status application pool iis7 with csharp (access-denied)

Tags: c#, iis-7, access-denied

I need to monitor the status of an application in the applications pool of IIS 7 from another machine on the same domain. My monitoring application must be in C# and running as a Windows service.

On my server, I create a user with administration rights and I execute the command `aspnet_regiis -ga machine\username` which worked successfully.

My problem is when I try to access the application pool I still get COMExcepttion "Access denied".
What did I do wrong or which step did I miss?

I used code from http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/create-a-website-application-pool-programmatically-using-csharp as example.

```
        int status = 0;
        string ipAddress = "10.20.2.13";
        string username = "username";
        string password = "password";
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("IIS://{0}/W3SVC/AppPools/MyAppPoolName", ipAddress), username, password);

            //the exception is thrown here.
            status = (int)de.InvokeGet("AppPoolState");

            switch (status)
            {
                case 2:
                    //Running
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //Stopped
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you found seems to be for IIS6. Perhaps you will be better off using the new and supported IIS7 management API. You could start by calling [ServerManager.OpenRemote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.openremote(v=VS.90).aspx) to get the [ServerManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager(v=VS.90).aspx) object.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll take a look at it. I'll give you feedback

Comment: Yes (with DCOM) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544640/microsoft-web-administration-on-windows-xp/2744440#2744440

Answer (score 0):

You might need to mess around with the [AuthenticationType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx), the default starting with 2.0 is Secure but you might need to set SSL. Also, I've seen Access Denied messages from accounts with the "user must change password on next logon" checked.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well on Windows 7 and Windows server 2008 (unfortunately not on XP and 2003 Server). I had to add Management Service role in the IIS via the Server Manager in order to enable remote connection.

Here's an short example of how to get the State of an Application Pool.

```
public ObjectState State
    {
        get
        {
            ServerManager server = null;
            ObjectState result = ObjectState.Unknown;
            try
            {
                server = ServerManager.OpenRemote(address);
                result = server.ApplicationPools[name].State;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (server != null)
                    server.Dispose();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Thanks to driis.